# System.Net.Mail - Invalid Characters in Mail Address

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, smtp

How can I send an email using SYstem.Net.Mail to an email address that is unusual (myFirstName.O'Reilly@mywebsite.com) but is still [RFC 5322](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address) compliant?

Does .NET support sending mail addresses that have single quotes in them, and if so, how do I force the system to allow email to be sent to those addresses? Right now we're using the System.Net.Mail class to send mail, but it's bombing on those specific types of email addresses.

Comment: not sure but i think there was some kind of encoding property when you create the mail body

Comment: Can you list the specific exception, message, and the relevant part of the stack trace, or at least what call you made?  Apostrophes do pass address validation in Sytem.Net.Mail.MailAddress.

Comment: not supporting quotes in content , what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/84dd5b66-f68d-4b0c-823f-25aa7c7b4d6b/

i.e. create MailAddress("myFirstName.O'Reilly@mywebsite.com"), and then use that to create a MailMessage, and pass to SmtpClient.Send.